# Create a new variable that is the summation from the first value

Tags: r, dplyr

This is something that should be simple but I can't figure it out. I have a variable `var` and need to create another variable `var2` that is calculated adding the value of `var` from the first observation. The problem is that the value of `var2` at the first observation (a) should be 14, not 28. I tried a solution using the function `first` but it didn't work out and that's because everything is added to 14, even the first observation.

CODE:

```
library(dplyr)

data_a <- read.csv(text = "
obs,var
a, 14
b, 124
c, 180
d, 40
e, 20
") 

data_b <- data_a %>%
  mutate(var2 = first(var) + var)
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

The expected result should have a value of 14 for `var2` at observation `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if *row_number* is bigger than 1, then update:

```
data_a %>%
  mutate(var2 = ifelse(row_number() > 1, first(var) + var, var))
#   obs var var2
# 1   a  14   14
# 2   b 124  138
# 3   c 180  194
# 4   d  40   54
# 5   e  20   34
```